# SQL JOIN WIth null

Tags: sql, join

What can I do do make my statement return Null when there is no row with `D.MetaDataID = '580c215f-54cb-4449-8368-7d740be71973'` and the Data Table?

I've tried Left JOIN But nothing changes... :(

```
SELECT 
D.Value
FROM dbo.Item I
JOIN dbo.Data D ON D.ItemID = I.ID
WHERE  I.ItemTypeID = '14ea6709-1bf8-4d5c-9090-3ace3cc42874' --Instance.album
       AND D.MetaDataID = '580c215f-54cb-4449-8368-7d740be71973' --freepacks
```

Comment: Why is a one row, one column table with the null value better than a zero row, one column table? Why not simply handle a zero row resultset?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need a `LEFT JOIN` and to move the condition on `D` into the `ON` clause rather than `WHERE`. In the `WHERE` clause this converts your query back into an inner join.

```
SELECT D.Value
FROM   dbo.Item I
       LEFT JOIN dbo.Data D
         ON D.ItemID = I.ID
            AND D.MetaDataID = '580c215f-54cb-4449-8368-7d740be71973'
--freepacks
WHERE  I.ItemTypeID = '14ea6709-1bf8-4d5c-9090-3ace3cc42874' --Instance.album
```

Comment: Thx @Martin I didn't know putting the `AND D.MetaDataID = '580c215f-54cb-4449-8368-7d740be71973'`in the where clause would make any difference

Comment: @ShadowG - The non matching rows will have `NULL` in the `D.MetaDataID` column so the `WHERE` clause then eliminates them.

Comment: Hey @Martin, if I use `ORDER BY CAST(D.Value AS DATETIME) ASC`  clause, whatever is null  comes first. Do you know how can I get around this?

Comment: `ORDER BY CASE WHEN D.Value IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, CAST(D.Value AS DATETIME) ASC`

Answer (score 0):

Make it a `LEFT JOIN`. Left joins will preserve every row from the original table (`dbo.Item`), even if the table being joined (`dbo.Data`) would be `NULL`. Of course, then you also can't require `dbo.Data.anything` to be nonzero in your `on` clause so you should probably remove that criterion.